# Difficulty Loading PHAR Package in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I am attempting to use a set of PHP classes for encryption here: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

I have downloaded the PHAR file and uploaded it to my server, but it does not work. From the installation instructions, it just seems like you pass the file's path to require_once and then you can use it, but I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Key' not found in G:\PleskVhosts\insurancemidam.com\httpdocs\test\confirmation.php on line 4
```

Here is some of my PHP:

```
require_once('defuse-crypto.phar');
include('header.php');
$key = Key::createNewRandomKey();
echo $key->saveToAsciiSafeString();
```

I have tried putting it in 'header.php' with no success either.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Try the full path to the file. Make sure you meet the requirements. "This library requres no special dependencies except for PHP 5.4 or newer with the OpenSSL extensions enabled (this is the default)."

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I still could not get it to work even though I have tried numerous file path combinations, OpenSSL is enabled, and I am running PHP 5.4. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289

Answer (score 1):

put the following line at the top of your script just under the require_once statement:

```
use \Defuse\Crypto\Key
```

It has to do with namespace